# Output ActiveRecord MySQL queries to page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

New to rails so bear with me :)

How would I go about appending all of the queries executed by ActiveRecord for each page request to the bottom of the page (i.e. application layout)? Coming from CakePHP, this is a useful tool for ensuring the code I'm writing is efficient.

I know I can change the logger via ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT), for example, but what would I add in to my layout file to dump a list of the queries being executed? Is there a way for me to configure the ActiveRecord logger to a variable, say in my environment.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [rails footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes) gem - I think it will likely do what you want here, and give you more features as well.  I haven't used it as much lately, but I used it extensively in some Rails v2 apps we had, and I just added it to a Rails v3 application to make sure it still worked as expected (and found some slow queries that need correcting as well! )